# Download Private Github Repository From Powershell Returning a 404

Tags: git, rest, powershell, github, http-headers

I am trying to download a private repository from Github using a powershell command. I need to download the file as a zip, and cannot use any Git commands. Here is the script I am using:

```
$AccessToken = "XXXXXXXXX"

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "token $AccessToken")

$gurl = "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/zipball/master"

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $gurl -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "C:\testing\repo.zip"
```

When running this I receive a 404 not found error.

According to Github "The API supports Basic Authentication as defined in RFC2617 with a few slight differences. The main difference is that the RFC requires unauthenticated requests to be answered with 401 Unauthorized responses. In many places, this would disclose the existence of user data. Instead, the GitHub API responds with 404 Not Found"

Running the command without headers for a public repository does not give any issues. For example,

```
$gurl = "https://api.github.com/repos/business/public-repo/zipball/master"

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $gurl -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "C:\testing\repo.zip"
```

For this reason, I believe the issue is with the Authentication process, I have made sure to give the Personal Access Token the appropriate permissions for access. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed with your authentication. When you provide an Authorization header, you need to specify the type of authentication (which you've said is `token`) and then the credential.

However, the GitHub API requires Basic authentication, which requires you to specify a username and password delimited by a colon, which the result base64 encoded. So if you wanted to specify the username as "token" and the token value as "abc123", then your Authorization header would look have the value `Basic dG9rZW46YWJjMTIz`, which the the base64 encoding of `token:abc123`.

For the GitHub API, you can use the token as either the username or password, but it's customary to use it as the password and fill in a dummy value for the username, such as "token", as I did above.

Comment: Also, How did you know that the authentication was basic? I see Github allows for both Oauth2 authentication and Basic authentication. I thought the one I was using is oauth. Thanks again.

Comment: I made a guess based on the script you provided. You could also use `Bearer TOKEN` if you want to do the OAuth2 thing. The GitHub API doesn't care either way.